# Windows Phone 8 Map incremental movement based on series of coordinates

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I want to have a map control on Windows Phone move between coordinates one by one. I cannot seem to get the the map control to wait until the animation has finished reaching one location before it tries to move to the next. I have tried a few ways to get it to wait between movements to no avail. Here is the code I have so far as a sample app.

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        map.Center = new GeoCoordinate(54.958879, -7.733027);
        map.ZoomLevel = 13;
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Location> locations = new List<Location>();

        for (double x = 0, y = 0; y < 10; x+=0.005, y++)
        {
            locations.Add(new Location(54.958879 + x, -7.733027 + x));
            locations.Add(new Location(54.958879 - x, -7.733027 - x));
        }

        foreach (Location location in locations)
        {
            map.SetView(new GeoCoordinate(location.Latitude, location.Longitude), 13, MapAnimationKind.Linear);   
//I want the app to wait until this view has finished moving before moving again 
        }
    }

    class Location
    {
        public double Latitude { get; set; }
        public double Longitude { get; set; }

        public Location(double lat, double lon)
        {
            Latitude = lat;
            Longitude = lon;
        }
    }
```

I am sure I am missing something simple. Can someone help solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a `DispatcherTimer` and on the `Tick` event, iterate to the next coord and then call `SetView`.

for example:

```
private DispatcherTimer timer;
private int index = 0;
List<Location> locations = new List<Location>();
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer
    {
        Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) // TODO: your interval
    };
    timer.Tick += timer_Tick;
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    locations.Clear();
    for (double x = 0, y = 0; y < 10; x+=0.005, y++)
    {
        locations.Add(new Location(54.958879 + x, -7.733027 + x));
        locations.Add(new Location(54.958879 - x, -7.733027 - x));
    }
    timer.Start();
}

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = locations[index];
    map.SetView(new Geocoordinate(item.Latitude, item.Longitude), 13, MapAnimationKind.Linear);
    if(index >= locations.Count)
        timer.Stop();
    else
        index++;
}
```

Comment: Could you give me a code example? Im not competent enough with this to just whip up the solution based on an explanation :)

Comment: @Kazuo Added an example.

Comment: Hey, based on the code you provided I was able to create a crude solution that I can build upon but the actual code in your answer is buggy. You need to remove the `List<Location> locations = new List<Location>();` from inside the Button_Click or the global list of locations will not populate. Once that is fixed the map seems to jump around between coordinates and certainly no in the order added. Odd. Thanks for your help though

Comment: Thanks, just typed it into Stackoverflow, I didn't compile/scan it :) Fixed.